# Project Euler 549 - My functions are not returning the answer it's supposed to return and I don't know what's wrong

Tags: c#, function, project

The [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=549) states the following:

> The smallest number m such that 10 divides m! is m = 5.
>   The smallest number m such that 25 divides m! is m = 10.
>
> Let s(n) be the smallest number m such that n divides m!.
>
> So s(10) = 5 and s(25) = 10.
>
> Let S(n) be ∑s(i) for 2 ≤ i ≤ n.
>   S(100) = 2012.
>
> Find S(10^8).

I made a function for factorials and a function for s(n) which when I tested them worked perfectly but when testing my next function S(n) it returned *1805* as an answer instead of *2012* that I should've gotten.

```
public class Program
{
    public static long Factorial(long i) {
            if (i <= 1)
                return 1;
            return i * Factorial(i - 1);
    }


    public static long s(long n) {
        bool dontStop = true;
        for (long i = 0; dontStop; i++) {
            if (Factorial(i)%n == 0) {
                dontStop = false;
                return i;
                break;
            }     
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static long S(long n) {
        long count = 0;
        for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            //Console.WriteLine(count);
            count += s(i);
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(S(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: So answer this, did you debug and breakpoint your application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type `long` is simply not nearly "big enough" for high factorials, and with high I mean larger than 20 because:

```
Console.WriteLine(Factorial(20));
Console.WriteLine(long.MaxValue);
```

returns

```
2432902008176640000
9223372036854775807
```

As you can see, they are in the same order of magnitude, which means that `long` isn't suited for even `Factorial(21)` and indeed it returns `-4249290049419214848`.

You should use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, which can store arbitrarily large integers.

Comment: I never thought of long being too small for my numbers, I'm dumb, thank you. I didn't even know BigInteger existed but I did some research and found out more about.

Comment: @Axel: even if you use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, calculating S(10^8) in a naive brute force manner will definitely last too long.

Comment: @DocBrown Yeah you are right. Do you have any other ideas? I don't know what else to do